# How can I develop a game engine that supports android

Tags: mobile, game-engine

I am thinking about developing a game engine in which I can make games for android and other mobile platforms and I have no clue for it.I just see tutorials for making game engine just for one specific platform and have not found any tutorials for making a game engine for various kinds of platforms!.please give me some clues for it

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you read [Game and Graphics Programming for iOS and Android with OpenGL ES 2.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119975913), if you really want to make game engine for Android. His projects sample is too old and written on Eclipse (which is deprecated by Google for Android development), it take me a lot of time to convert his old project to Android Studio. His source code is very small but run smoothly on new devices. His project also include iOS XCode project too, but also some minor modify to migrate older XCode to newer. Two Android and iOS projects sharing ~ 95% C source code (truly cross-platform) and some platform code (Java for Android and Objective-C for iOS but it just only ~ 5%).

I am also recommend you consider use OpenGL ES graphic API for cross-platform game engine instead of using multiple graphic API, because you can use [Google ANGLE](https://github.com/google/angle) project to convert OpenGL ES graphic API to native API for other devices like DirectX (Windows PC, Windows Phone), Metal (MacOS, iOS), Vulkan, Desktop OpenGL just one code base. The most successful game engine base on OpenGL ES API is [Godot Engine](https://github.com/godotengine/godot). One of the most the popular project using ANGLE is Google Chrome.

In 2014, Apple announce they deprecated OpenGL ES for their Metal API (but I am tested OpenGL ES project still run on new iOS 13), so only choice if using OpenGL ES is ANGLE. If you want to follow ANGLE Metal you can follow [here](https://github.com/kakashidinho/metalangle)

Initialize when Microsoft create Windows Runtime (Windows Store, Windows Phone) is just support DirectX, but they also create tutorial for ANGLE to convert OpenGL ES to DirectX, see tutorial [here](https://github.com/Microsoft-Build-2016/CodeLabs-GameDev-3-ANGLE)